# Writing a Simple Logger with Timestamp and Counter in Jython

Tags: logging, timestamp, jython, sikuli

I'm trying to write a simple logger in Jython, and I can't seem to find any working examples online.

I have checked http://www.jython.org/docs/library/logging.html but the code doesn't seem to work for me.

I just want to have a simple loop that logs a string with a **timestamp** and a message (log number/count) to a log file every thirty seconds. I am doing this in Windows using [Sikuli](http://sikuli.org).

Example of log message:

```
2012-04-26 13:25:51 message number 75
```

Can anyone help me out.

Thanks in advance,

Marwan

PS - I have never used Jython before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For such a simple thing you can write simple routine:

```
import time

LOG_CNT = 0

def log(msg):
    global LOG_CNT
    LOG_CNT += 1
    dts = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    f = open('log.txt', 'a')
    f.write('%s: msg# %d: %s\n' % (dts, LOG_CNT, msg))
    f.close()


def test():
    log('zorro')
    time.sleep(5)
    log('bubu')


test()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

@Michał Niklas answer is much better, but an alternative is to use the python print statement which logs to stdout.

```
def log(msg):
    global LOG_CNT
    LOG_CNT += 1
    dts = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print dts + "msg#" + LOG_CNT + msg
```

If running Sikuli from the command line, this can be piped to a file.

sikli-ide.exe myProject.sikuli > stdoutfile.txt

Sikuli also logs internal messages as well so this is a much uglier solution than creating your own logfile, but may come in handy especially when writing/debugging sikuli scripts.

Comment: This looks great. Thanks. I like the pipping idea too.